# summernote icons not showing in line

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

i work with sommernote editor. i getting problem with sommernote icons.
here is the image.
[image]

i want all icon in one line.

here is my code

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
    toolbar: [
        // [groupName, [list of button]]
        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
        ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
        ['insert', ['link','hr']],
        ['Misc',['fullscreen','help']]
    ]
    });
```

Comment: are you including the required css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is bootstrap.css and summurnote.css is overriding.

Comment: when i include css file first i include bootstrap.css and than  summurnote.css